# Eclipse RCP how to re-initialise a view. (Need to do this as work around to table bug)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a basic RCP application with one perspective and a couple of views attached at start up, it basically loads a varied column length csv file in to a table.

The view that contains the table is where my problem is because the user can do some basic things that interact with the table, certain columns get highlighted etc. But the user is able to load another file whenever they want. And the table view listens for changes in the file source provider to do this. When a change to data occurs the table does this:

```
@Override
public void sourceChanged(int sourcePriority, String sourceName,
        Object sourceValue) {
    if (sourceName == AbstractSampleDataSourceProvider.SAMPLE_DATA_KEY) {

        for (TableColumn c : viewer.getTable().getColumns()) {
            c.dispose();
        }

        SampleData sData = (SampleData) sourceValue;
        createColumns(sData);
        viewer.setInput(sData.getDataSet());
    }
}
```

This code works sometime, but inconsistently errors out with an error that I believe is actually an issue with the JFace Tables:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getData(Widget.java:558)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getViewerColumn(ColumnViewer.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider$OwnerDrawListener.handleEvent(OwnerDrawLabelProvider.java:47)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.sendMeasureItemEvent(Table.java:3766)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.CDDS_SUBITEMPREPAINT(Table.java:998)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.wmNotifyChild(Table.java:6840)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:5534)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:1896)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:5086)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4584)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4985)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5893)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5893)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3275)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.destroyItem(Table.java:2066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn.destroyWidget(TableColumn.java:194)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:818)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:446)
at mypackage.rcp.viewpart.SampleDataTableView.sourceChanged(SampleDataTableView.java:130)
at org.eclipse.ui.AbstractSourceProvider.fireSourceChanged(AbstractSourceProvider.java:80)
at mypackage.rcp.service.SampleDataSourceProvider.setSampleData(SampleDataSourceProvider.java:73)
at mypackage.rcp.handler.LoadRawDataHandler.execute(LoadRawDataHandler.java:56)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
```

Nothing amazing interesting or insightful there from what I can tell.

Anyway I'm thinking that my solution to this problem is to either re-instantiate the view (can I do this) or to dispose of my view entirely and generate a new one in the same position before the data changed listeners are hit up. So that each time it's a brand new table that's begin used.

Either way, I have no idea how to do this, so thoughts and suggestions would be much appreciated. (in fact if anyone knows how to prevent the bug that would be better)

Regards,

Glen x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just dispose the table and recreate it? Should be less troublesome than reopening the whole view. Or to avoid the bug you could try to set a dummy label provider to replace the `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` before disposing the column.

Comment: I couldn't work out how to dispose of the table. I'm not sure you can because the viewer registers itself with the parent on view creation.

Comment: Create a `Composite` between the parent you get in `createPartControl(Composite parent)` and your Table(Viewer) (i.e. your new composite will be the parent of your table). Then you dispose the table and create a new as child of your composite.